# Swiping issue: After swiping page a white screen appears on phone

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework

I want to show a previous page when I fully swipe the current page. I am using the `onSwipeRight` function, but I am getting a white screen. I have already tried to solve this issue with the following:

I used following code in controller file:

```
$scope.onSwipeRight = function () {
    console.log("onSwipeRight");
    $state.go('app.monthtodate');
}
```

I used this code in HTML page:

```
on-swipe-right="onSwipeRight()"
```

Comment: Can you provide html codes please?